# Is it possible to globally change the default length for varchar fields (hbm2ddl)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

By adding the annotation "@Column(length = 1000)" to String variables you can increase the maximum length of the resulting varchar fields from 255 to 1000 (hbm2ddl):

```
@Column(length = 1000) // => varchar2(1000)
private String field1;

@Column(length = 1000) // => varchar2(1000)
private String field2;

@Column(length = 1000) // => varchar2(1000)
private String field3;
```

Is it possible to globally change the default length for all resulting varchar fields instead?

Answer (score 1):

No that isn't possible.  The `255` value is the default specified by JPA.